# Is there any possibility to override dimension text in Altium?

Tags: altium

I need to place a dimension on a assembly drawing. One of the element I need to be measured shown with a cut (see the arrow place):

[image]

So the wire need to be 200 mm, but the dimension text is only 18 (exactly the size on the drawing). I need to replace this text manually.

However the text in the textbox "Sample" is not editable. I can not hide wrong text either.

Any ideas how to make this possible?

**UPDATE**

Just found one way to go: in the format section choose "None" and the text gone:

[image]

However I'd like to keep the question for any case there is any better solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can delete the text selecting "Format" equal none. Then you can use the "Prefix" and "Suffix" menus to add a specific text.

The "Sample" box will be updated accordingly.

[image]

Comment: There isn't any other solution I can think of.

Comment: That is a perfect solution! Thank you for the answer. Here is your bounty :)